# Exercise 3 on page 5 and exercise 7 on page 6 in Koblitz's Introduction to modular forms.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-forms

I want to prove $1$ cannot be a congruent number, by using the fact that if it were congruent then the equation $x^4-y^4=u^2$ would have a solution in integers with $u$ being odd.

I proved this last claim, but I don't see how to assert from this claim a contradiction.

Can anyone provide me with hints?
I assume that I am missing some result in number theory.

As for exercise 7a, it asks me to show that condition B of Tunnel's theorem always holds for if $n$ is congruent to $5$ or $7$ modulo $8$.

Tunnell's theorem states the following:

Let $n$ be an odd squarefree natural number.
Consider the two conditions:
$(A)$ $n$ is a congruent number;

$(B)$ the number of triples of integers $(x,y,z)$ satisfying $2x^2+y^2+8z^2 = n$ is equal to twice the number of triples satisfying $2x^2+y^2+32z^2 = n $, then $(A)$ implies $(B)$ and if a weak form of Birch-Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture is true, then $(B)$ also implies $(A)$.

Now I am stuck on showing that condition $(B)$ is satisfied by $n = 8m+5$.
How to show that the number of triples $(x,y,z)$ satisfying $2x^2+y^2+8z^2 = 5+8m$ is twice the number of triples that satisfy: $2x^2+y^2+32z^2 = 8m+5$; I thought of moving the $8m$ to the LHS.
I thought of the fact that $z \mapsto \pm 2z$ changes one equation to another, but not sure how to continue from there.

Any tips?

Thanks in advance.

P.S
A congruent number is a rational number which is the area of some right triangle with rational sides, i.e $r$ is called a congruent number if there exist rational numbers $X,Y,Z$ s.t $X^2+Y^2=Z^2 , XY/2=r$.

Comment: Including the definition of a congruent number in the question would be appreciated (at least by me) so folks need not look it up. Also, in $A \implies B$ are you assuming that $n=5+8m$ is a congruent number, and going for a separate (direct) verification of (B) without using the presumably known implication $A \implies B$? Excuse my unfamiliarity with the definitions, but it does seem unclear what you are going for in the question.

Comment: @coffeemath I want to show that condition $(B)$ is satisfied by $n=5+8m$ and $n=7+8m$. How do you show that $n$ in either case is a congruent number?

Comment: There is a not hard descent proof that the equation $x^4-y^4=z^2$ has no solutions other than the obvious ones.

Comment: MathPhys--Still don't see the definition of congruent number in your post. Is it too involved?

Comment: @AndréNicolas if you have a reference or can provide the proof then that would be terrific. BTW you meant "decent" and not "descent".

Comment: @coffeemath I now mean to edit it.

Comment: @coffeemath I edited my original post.

Comment: I searched using Google, typing Fermat difference of fourth powers a square and got a bunch of hits, the first few of which are good. The argument is due to Fermat. The result, or the result about $x^4+y^4=z^2$, which uses essentially the same method, is proved in many first number theory books.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I found a theorem in the book of Burton's, the theorem says that that the diophantine equation $x^4-y^4 = z^2$ doesn't have solution in natural numbers $x,y,z$.

Comment: Yes, that's the result that is being used to get the contradiction. It is such a standard result that the author felt detail was unnecessary.

Comment: @AndréNicolas can you help me with the second question in this post? thanks in advance.

Comment: In reply to your earlier comment, I did mean *descent*, an abbreviation for *infinite descent*, and not *decent*.

Comment: @AndréNicolas can you help me with exercise 7a from Koblitz's?

Comment: At first glance I do not know how to do it, will favourite it and think a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reading a text and not trying to actually compute anything might not be a good advice for learning math, especially number theory.
Prof. Koblitz have written the question in a rather obscure manner, but trying to actually put some numbers in the equation reveals the trick.

I claim that when $m=5,7 \bmod(8)$, there are **NO** solutions for the congruence.
By looking $\bmod (2)$ one figures out that $y$ is odd, hence $y^2\equiv 1 \bmod(8)$ therefore one left with $2x^2\equiv 4,6 \bmod(8)$, which have no solutions.